# Cómo continuar el consecutivo correcto en los registros devueltos por el paginador?

Tags: symfony2

estoy empleando KnpPaginatorBundles para mostrar resultados paginados. El paginador funciona perfecto, excepto que en la vista la columna que muestra el número de registro en cada fila, al pasar de páginas inicia siempre en 1, obviamente porque uso `{{ loop.index }}` en la plantilla `twig`. Cuál sería la forma adecuada de iniciar el conteo. Por páginas se muestran 10 registros.

*filas_tabla_riesgoInfantil.html.twig:*

```
{% for riesgosPaginador in riesgo %}
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ loop.index }}</td>
        <td class="text-nowrap">{{ riesgo.nombre }}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{{ riesgo.descripcion }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ riesgo.calificaComoAltoRiesgo }}</td>
        {% if is_granted({'ROLE_ESP_NAC':'ROLE_ESP_NAC', 'ROLE_ESP_PROV':'ROLE_ESP_RPOV', 'ROLE_ESP_MUN':'ROLE_ESP_MUN'}) and puedeGestionarCodificador == true %}
            <td class="text-center"><a class="lnkEditaRegistro" href="{{ path('riesgo_infantil_editar', {'id':riesgo.id}) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
            <td class="text-center"><a class="lnkEliminaRegistro" href="{{ path('riesgo_infantil_eliminar', {'id':riesgo.id}) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
                {% endif %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Estuve revisando el bundle y no encuentro alguna función que me de este valor, es decir que me pueda servir para iniciar el numero de registro en el índice adecuado.
Tal vez basándome en el número de la página y el máximo por página pudiera calcularse.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, resolví como explicaba jugando un poco con el numero de pagina actual y la variable index del ciclo twig.

```
    {% set paginaActual = riesgosPaginador.currentPageNumber %}
    {% set numeroRegistro = 0 %}
    {% if paginaActual > 1 %}
       {% if paginaActual == 2 %}
            {% set numeroRegistro = 10 %}
       {% elseif paginaActual > 2 %}
            {% set numeroRegistro = (paginaActual-1) * 10 %}
       {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% for riesgo in riesgosPaginador %}
       <tr>
         <td class="text-center">{{ numeroRegistro + loop.index }}</td>
         <td class="text-nowrap">{{ riesgo.nombre }}</td>
         <td class="text-left">{{ riesgo.descripcion }}</td>
         <td class="text-center">{{ riesgo.calificaComoAltoRiesgo }}</td>
         {% if is_granted({'ROLE_ESP_NAC':'ROLE_ESP_NAC', 'ROLE_ESP_PROV':'ROLE_ESP_RPOV', 'ROLE_ESP_MUN':'ROLE_ESP_MUN'}) and puedeGestionarCodificador == true %}
            <td class="text-center"><a class="lnkEditaRegistro" href="{{ path('riesgo_infantil_editar', {'id':riesgo.id}) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
            <td class="text-center"><a class="lnkEliminaRegistro" href="{{ path('riesgo_infantil_eliminar', {'id':riesgo.id}) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
         {% endif %}
      </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```